# Tuning a query in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a query which is to check if the table_A amount is equal to sum of amount in Table_B. The query works fine but since i am learning on how to improve myself in using optimised query i wanted to check with experts.

```
      Update TABLE_A ln 
         set status_code='E' 
             , reject_reason='Outstanding loan amount not matching'
       where outs_Amt != (select SUM(ld.AMT)
                          from TABLE_B ld 
                         where ln.ssn = ld.ssn
                           and ln.id = ld.id 
                           and ln.status_code IN ('N','E')
                           and ld.status_code IN ('N','E')
                          group by ssn,ld.id)
         AND outs_Amt>0;
```

Like i asked is there any better way to re-write the above query?

Comment: Your query does not work if there are no corresponding entries in B. Is this intentional? It will work when you remove `group by` and add `nvl`: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a7115bb15d5e73ae4ab2ef5147fac18). `Group by` seems unnecessary.

Comment: yes it is intentional.

Comment: Start from generating an explain plan - run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR update ... rest of your query` and next `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`, and then copy a text  (not bitmap!!!) of a result of the last query and paste it into the question (use EDIT button to do it).